# dpkg-buildpackage creates empty package

Tags: debian, packaging, dpkg

I'm having troubles with the fundamentals of debian packaging. I'm trying to package qt which I am compiling with some specific configuration flags.  This is so my colleagues can use the package without re-compiling it for themselves.  This question isn't related to qt, it's just the project that I'm building.

## How I'm creating the package:

#### Get the package:

Run these commands.  Alternatively, extract the tarball contents to this folder to take advantage of the pre-generated files

```
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.10/5.10.0/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0.tar.xz
tar -xf qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0.tar.xz
cd qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0
```

#### Generate the debian build system instructions:

```
DEBFULLNAME="My name"
dh_make --email email@company.com                   \
         --file=../qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0.tar.xz  \
         -s                                         \
         --packagename=sim-qt                       \
         --copyright=lgpl
```

#### Configure the debian build system instructions:

Edit these fields of debian/control:

```
Section: devel
Homepage: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.10/5.10.0/single/
Description: My Qt build
```

Edit debian/rules to look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
        dh $@  --with autotools-dev --parallel

override_dh_auto_configure:
        ./configure --prefix=/opt/sim-qt           \
                    --opensource --confirm-license \
                    --skip=qtcharts                \
                    --skip=qtvirtualkeyboard       \
                    --skip=qtdatavis3d             \
                    --skip=qtwebengine             \
                    --silent                       \
                    --nomake=examples              \
                    --nomake=tests
```

#### Build the package:

```
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -nc
```

I'm using `-nc` because it takes over an hour to compile.  I don't want to re-compile if I don't need to and I've been using dpkg-buildpackage a lot over the past few days.

## The problem

The package is empty!

```
stew@stewbian:~/src/qt$ dpkg --contents sim-qt_5.10.0-1_amd64.deb
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-03-14 10:36 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-03-14 10:36 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-03-14 10:36 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-03-14 10:36 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2018-03-14 10:36 ./usr/share/doc/sim-qt/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       188 2018-03-14 10:36 ./usr/share/doc/sim-qt/README.Debian
-rw-r--r-- root/root       188 2018-03-14 10:36 ./usr/share/doc/sim-qt/changelog.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1440 2018-03-14 10:36 ./usr/share/doc/sim-qt/copyright
```

Also, the content that *should* be in the package seems to be installed on my local machine.

Comment: Ok so maybe the problem is Qt-related.  `make install DESTDIR=some/other/path` seems to ignore the DESTDIR argument.  This is used by dpkg-buildpackage

Comment: I've seen that when I've used QMake to build stuff.  I'll write an answer with my workaround.

Comment: You do know you can get Debian's packaging for Qt, and just adapt that?

Comment: Yes, but wow, qt5-default is a VERY complicated multi-part package.  A single deb file is all I'm looking for.  I'm going through your answer now, trying to figure out where I can set QMAKE_ARGS from

Comment: Yes, it's big.  But you can get *just the `debian` directory*, and extract the magic you need from there.  I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem I've seen when using QMake to build.

The usual `install` target made by QMake uses a variable called `INSTALL_ROOT` instead of `DESTDIR` that `dpkg` expects.

When I build Qt binaries, I add to my QMake arguments:

```make
QMAKE_ARGS += INSTALL_ROOT=$(DESTDIR) DESTDIR=
```

If I don't null out `DESTDIR`, it tries to use both `INSTALL_ROOT` and `DESTDIR` for some reason.

I also have a `PREFIX` definition; I don't know whether you'll need that:

```make
QMAKE_ARGS +=  PREFIX=/usr
```

Finally, it's worth telling Qt not to strip the binaries (`dh_strip` will do that, and you'll want it to if you'd like to have symbols packages to go with your binaries):

```make
QMAKE_ARGS += QMAKE_STRIP=:
```

---

And then, use those arguments when I run QMake:

```make
$(PROJECT)/Makefile: $(PROJECT)/my_project.pro
    @test -d $(@D) || mkdir -p $(@D) || test -d $(@D)
    $(QMAKE) -o $@ $< $(QMAKE_ARGS)
```

Comment: Yes, you described the problem well.  This helped me solve the problem!  I couldn't easily figure out how to add those arguments to QMAKE_ARGS from the `./configure` line and so instead I just changed the `--prefix` from `/opt/sim-qt` to `debian/sim-qt/opt/sim-qt`.  When QMake fails to read the DESTDIR argument, it will go ahead and install it to the location I actually want.  No more "pretending" that we are installing to root, we'll just install to where we need to be for packaging.  A bit hacky, but I couldn't afford the time for a real solution.